# Xamarin Forms modal navigation causes exception

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

When I try to `useModalNavigation` set to `true` using Prism in my Xamarin Forms app, I receive a `ClassCastException` when executing my command.

It is working in two other places in my app. The way I am executing this method is as follows:

### Command

```
private DelegateCommand _filterCommand;
public DelegateCommand FilterCommand 
    => _filterCommand ?? (_filterCommand = new 
        DelegateCommand(ExecuteFilterCommand).ObservesCanExecute(vm => CanNavigate));
```

### ExecuteFilterCommand

```
private void ExecuteFilterCommand()
{
    CanNavigate = false;
    _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MainNavigationPage/FilterLinesPage", null, true);
    CanNavigate = true;
}
```

This is the exact way I'm doing it for the other filter commands I have, yet this causes an exception:

```
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to     android.view.ViewGroup
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1165)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1057)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:662)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I do not know if the causing problem is Prism or Xamarin Forms as this is somewhat new to me... it is working in other areas of the app.

I see, that one has ran into the exact problem as me [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54192/xamarin-forms-1-5-2-pre2-released/p3).

I just tried using Xamarins own Navigation, and I receive the exact same error, so I'm blaming this on Xamarin Forms. I am using `AppCompat`, maybe I need to update this?

It is working correctly on iOS - so this is only an Android issue.

Comment: I get the same problem except I'm not using Prism. This happens on one page, but not another and it's only when using a Modal push. If I don't wrap it in a NavigationPage then it doesn't crash but I don't get the navigation bar

Comment: Hi Peter! Create a sample that reproduces this with the latest Xamarin.Forms version from NuGet and file an issue here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Forms

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom renderers, be sure to set Ids on the native Android controls to avoid this issue.

This is a fairly rare exception that we've only seen when a modal window is pushed over a map. Good news, however: a fix is in the works, and it should no longer be an issue in the next stable version.

Comment: "This is a fairly rare exception that we've only seen when a modal window is pushed over a map. Good news, however: a fix is in the works, and it should no longer be an issue in the next stable version." - This is exactly the issue I am having. What version is this fixed in?